# How to check the date formats in LINUX

Tags: linux, unix, date

I am trying to check whether my input parameter is of pattern **YYYYMMDDN** or **YYYYMM**.

If my date input is in **YYYYMMDDN** format then I need to validate it and convert it into **MMNYY** format
If my date input is in **YYYYMM** format then I need to validate it and convert it into **YYMM** format.

Please kindly let me know how to accomplish this.

Comment: When you think "help" means "write something for me" - that won't work on SO. Try something on your own and come back if you have problems because somethign does not work as expected.

Comment: What is `YYYYMMDDN` format?

Comment: @SOaddict wouldn't you need YYYYMMDDNN, then, instead of YYYYMMDDN? After all, there are usually 52-ish weeks in a year, unless N is not base-10 encoded...

Comment: Clean and working solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37144230/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Following will work for a date in `YYYYMMDDN` or `YYYYMM` formats:

```
dt='201304203'
[[ $dt =~ ^[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})? ]] && echo "matched"
```

Though keep in mind that this will not validate your date.

**Alternatively** use sed:

```
echo $dt | sed -n '/^[0-9]\{6\}[0-9]\{0,3\}/p'
```

**Alternative #2** use grep:

```
echo $dt | grep -qP '^[0-9]{6}[0-9]{0,3}$'
```

then check the return code `$?` (1 means failed and 0 means matched)

**UPDATE:**

For YYYYMMDDN => MMNYY:

```
echo '201304203' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})[0-9]{2}([0-9])$/\2\3\1/'
```

For YYYYMM => YYMM:

```
echo '201304' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\2/'
```

Comment: I am executing it on Linux.

Comment: I understand its Linux but which shell? You can find out by running `echo $SHELL` command.

Comment: I am using Korn Shell (.ksh )

Comment: As I said above will run in bash only. Use bash and you will never go back to ksh :)

Comment: Alternatively from ksh you can do: `bash -c 'dt='201304203'; [[ $dt =~ ^[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})? ]] && echo "matched"'` to execute above command in bash

Comment: I can only do it in ksh anubhava.. :)

Comment: Hi Anubhava... Your sed is printing the value for any input I enter.What does it really do?

Comment: It will print only when input matches `^[0-9]{6}[0-9]{0,3}` otherwise it won't print anything

Comment: I also provided you an option of using grep.

Comment: Okay...thanks anubhava... Also I modified my question.. Can you help me regarding that too if pos.. :(

Comment: They worked perfectly fine Anubhav.But how do I validate the input dates.

Comment: I had said at start that `Though keep in mind that this will not validate your date.` Hint: You can use awk's mktime to validate it so I leave it to you to build the next solution.