# Validate date format in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, if-statement

I have to create a Shell Script wherein one of the parameters will be the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. My question is, how can I check if the Date passed as parameter really follows this Date Format? I tried to use the grep command as below:

```
if echo "$1" | grep -q '^[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9]\{4\}$'
```

but it didn't give the correct format because the day for example can be 33, 34, (...), that is not really the correct format. Anyone know something that can really check if the date passed really follows the format dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236374/106927

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [date](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html)

```
date "+%d/%m/%Y" -d "09/99/2013" > /dev/null  2>&1
 is_valid=$?
```

The date string must be in "MM/DD/YYYY" format.

If you do not get 0 then date is in invalid format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This really works but just for format mm/dd/yyyy . If you check on terminal the option -d check just the format mm/dd/yyyy. I tried to change the format but it not affects the way as the option -d for date command is used.

Comment: WTF? The question was ``how can I check if the Date passed as parameter really follows this Date Format``. This doesn't check anything. ``date`` accepts dates in different formats. For example ``tomorrow`` is a valid format, ``date -d 'tomorrow + 5 months 20:00:01`` is valid as well.

Comment: Also ``date -d '05/20/1900'`` throws an error for me. It also depends on your architecture (the date range can be bigger for 64-bit systems). This is definitely not the way to go. Use [konsolebox's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736035/2698019) instead.

Comment: As pointed by Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko-A., this actually does not check the date format. To verify if dd is in YYYY-MM-DD format and is a valid date, one can do:

[[ $(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$dd") == "$dd" ]] || echo 'invalid date format'

Comment: that didn't work for me, for example: date "+%d/%m/%Y" -d "20/09/2013" is invalid, but is a valid date. It's really boring those differences between date command in the bash...

Comment: It just outputs current date and successfully exits if `-d` argument is empty or doesn't include separator.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest solution, that still works perfectly, is the following :

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && date -d "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
   ...
```

It consists in combining 2 checks :

- the first part checks that `$1` is of this format : `NNNN-NN-NN`
- the second part checks that it is a valid date

You need the two checks because :

- if you don't do the first check, `date` will exit with code 0 even if your variable is a valid date in **another format**
- if you don't do the second check, then you can end up with a 0 even for variables such as `2016-13-45`

Comment: the second check will succeed in case you don't use dashes. e.g. 20203112 will succeed in the date -d check.

Answer (score 6):

This function expects 2 strings,a format string, a date string

The format string uses the codes from the date command but does not include the '+'

The function returns 0 if the provided date matches the given format, otherwise it returns 1

**Code (my_script.sh)**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

datecheck() {
    local format="$1" d="$2"
    [[ "$(date "+$format" -d "$d" 2>/dev/null)" == "$d" ]]
}

date_test="$1"

echo $date_test
if datecheck "%d %b %Y" "$date_test"; then
    echo OK
else
    echo KO
fi
```

**Output**

```
$ ./my_script.sh "05 Apr 2020"
05 Apr 2020
OK
$ ./my_script.sh "foo bar"
foo bar
KO
```

Answer (score 5):

First, check the form of the input using the regex.  Then use awk to switch to mm/dd/yyyy and use date to validate.  You can use the following expression in your `if` statement:

```
echo "$1" | egrep -q '^[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9]{4}$' && date -d "$(echo "$1" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print $2"/"$1"/"$3}')" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Kudos for actually answering the OP's question and in a one-liner. The egrep regex can be simplified to `'^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$'` as the subsequent check with `date` will disqualify dates like 40/01/2020.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way for `dd/mm/yyyy` exactly in Bash is:

```
if [[ $1 == [0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]
```

Or

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9]{4}$ ]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP said _didn't_ work, since it accepts invalid dates like 33/19/2000.

Comment: @augurar Yes I could have made a more accurate one. But then again even the accepted solution could accept other formats not just `dd/mm/yyyy`. So I believe it wouldn't really matter now.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `awk`:

```
echo "31/12/1999" | awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 31 && $2 <= 12 && match($3, /^[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]$/)) ? "good" : "bad" }'
```

It prints "good" if its valid date else prints "bad"

Comment: This will validate dates like `31/02/2012` or `29/02/2001` or `31/04/2000` or... `:(`

Comment: I have the need to validate multiple date formats across multiple files, which I'll already be awking out to get the date. This solution fits the request better than KonsoleBox's or PxL's. That being said, the format of the date in the request is different then this solution. It should be
`echo "31/12/1999" | awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && match($3, /^[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]$/)) ? "good" : "bad" }'`
The only caveat is that `02/30/2014` would pass even though that's not a date, but this is still perfect for my needs.

Comment: For the year parameter, it's better to use [0-9], instead of [1-9]

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash

isDateInvalid()
{
    DATE="${1}"

    # Autorized separator char ['space', '/', '.', '_', '-']
    SEPAR="([ \/._-])?"

    # Date format day[01..31], month[01,03,05,07,08,10,12], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_1="((([123][0]|[012][1-9])|3[1])${SEPAR}(0[13578]|1[02])${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[01..30], month[04,06,09,11], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_2="(([123][0]|[012][1-9])${SEPAR}(0[469]|11)${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[01..28], month[02], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_3="(([12][0]|[01][1-9]|2[1-8])${SEPAR}02${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[29], month[02], year[1904..2096]
    DATE_4="(29${SEPAR}02${SEPAR}(19|20(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])))"

    # Match the date in the Regex

    if ! [[ "${DATE}" =~ "^(${DATE_1}|${DATE_2}|${DATE_3}|${DATE_4})$" ]]
    then
        echo -e "ERROR - '${DATE}' invalid!"
    else
        echo "${DATE} is valid"
    fi
}

echo
echo "Exp 1: "`isDateInvalid '12/13/3000'`
echo "Exp 2: "`isDateInvalid '12/11/2014'`
echo "Exp 3: "`isDateInvalid '12 01 2000'`
echo "Exp 4: "`isDateInvalid '28-02-2014'`
echo "Exp 5: "`isDateInvalid '12_02_2002'` 
echo "Exp 6: "`isDateInvalid '12.10.2099'`
echo "Exp 7: "`isDateInvalid '31/11/2000'`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to do some data validation this:

```
# Script expecting a Date parameter in MM-DD-YYYY format as input
verifyInputDate(){
    echo ${date} | grep '^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "Date is valid"
     else
          echo "Date is not valid"
     fi
}
```

Comment: This is no better than the OPs example. Dates like `99/87/0000` would pass your grep.

Answer (score 1):

`X="2016-04-21" then check for the below value being 1 or 0.

cal `echo $x | cut -c 6-7` `echo $x | cut -c 1-4` 2>/dev/null | grep -c `echo $x | cut -c 9-10`

If the value is 1, then it's valid, else it's not valid.

Comment: Do you mean "backticks"? You should enter them as such in your answer then, otherwise it won't work because at the moment they *are* single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give an extended answer for a slightly different format, but this can easily be changed to the dd/mm/YY format with the answers already given; it's tested on busybox (posix shell)

This is one of the first hits for web searches similar to "busybox posix shell script date" and "test format" or "validate" etc, so here my solution for busybox (tested with 1.29.3, 1.23.1)

```
#!/bin/sh

##########
#
# check if date valid in busybox
#   tested in busybox 1.29.3, 1.23.1
#
# call with:
#   $0 <yyyymmdd>
#
##########

mydate=$1

if echo $mydate | grep -qE '20[0-9][0-9](0[1-9]|1[0-2])([012][0-9]|3[01])'; then
    printf 'may be valid\n'

    date +%Y%m%d -d $mydate -D %Y%m%d > /dev/null  2>&1
    is_valid=$?
    if [ $is_valid -ne 0 ]; then
        printf 'not valid\n'
        return 1
    else
        mytestdate=$(date +%Y%m%d -d $mydate -D %Y%m%d)
        if [ $mydate -ne $mytestdate ]; then
            printf 'not valid, results in "%s"\n' "$mytestdate"
            return 1
        else
            printf 'valid\n'
        fi
    fi
else
    printf 'not valid (must be: <yyyymmdd>)\n'
    return 1
fi
```

as in busybox (1.29.3 & 1.23.1) you have responds like:

```
lxsys:~# date +%Y%m%d -d 20110229 -D "%Y%m%d"
20110301
```

I had the need to validate the date in some better way but i wanted to rely mostly on the system itself

so with

```
mytestdate=$(date +%Y%m%d -d $mydate -D %Y%m%d)
if [ $mydate -ne $mytestdate ]; then
    ...
fi
```

there is a second test - do we have a difference between the wanted or given format (input, `$mydate`) and the system interpretation (output, `$mytestdate`) of it ... if it's not the same, discard the date

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this bash script to validate date. I can accept mont as alphanumeric.

```
#!/bin/bash

function isDateValid {
    DATE=$1

    if [[ $DATE =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[0-9]{4}$ ]]; then
        echo "Date $DATE is a number!"
        day=`echo $DATE | cut -d'-' -f1`
        month=`echo $DATE | cut -d'-' -f2`
        year=`echo $DATE | cut -d'-' -f3`

                if [ "$month" == "01" ] || [ "$month" == "1" ]; then
                        month="Jan"
                elif [ "$month" == "02" ] || [ "$month" == "2" ]; then
                        month="Feb"
                elif [ "$month" == "03" ] || [ "$month" == "3" ]; then
                        month="Mar"
                elif [ "$month" == "04" ] || [ "$month" == "4" ]; then
                        month="Apr"
                elif [ "$month" == "05" ] || [ "$month" == "5" ]; then
                        month="May"
                elif [ "$month" == "06" ] || [ "$month" == "6" ]; then
                        month="Jun"
                elif [ "$month" == "07" ] || [ "$month" == "7" ]; then
                        month="Jul"
                elif [ "$month" == "08" ] || [ "$month" == "8" ]; then
                        month="Aug"
                elif [ "$month" == "09" ] || [ "$month" == "9" ]; then
                        month="Sep"
                elif [ "$month" == "10" ]; then
                        month="Oct"
                elif [ "$month" == "11" ]; then
                        month="Nov"
                elif [ "$month" == "12" ]; then
                        month="Dec"
                fi

        ymd=$year"-"$month"-"$day
        echo "ymd: "$ymd
        dmy=$(echo "$ymd" | awk -F- '{ OFS=FS; print $3,$2,$1 }')
        echo "dmy: "$dmy
        if date --date "$dmy" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo "OK"
            return 0
        else
                echo "NOK"
            return 1
        fi
    else
        echo "Date $DATE is not a number"
        return 1
    fi
}


if isDateValid "15-15-2014"; then
    echo "date is valid =)"
else
    echo "bad format date"
fi
echo "==================="
if isDateValid "15-12-2014"; then
        echo "date is valid =)"
else
        echo "bad format date"
fi
echo "==================="
if isDateValid "15-Dec-2014"; then
        echo "date is valid =)"
else
        echo "bad format date"
fi
echo "==================="
if isDateValid "1-May-2014"; then
        echo "date is valid =)"
else
        echo "bad format date"
fi
echo "==================="
if isDateValid "1-1-2014"; then
        echo "date is valid =)"
else
        echo "bad format date"
fi
echo "==================="
if isDateValid "12-12-2014"; then
        echo "date is valid =)"
else
        echo "bad format date"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the solution (if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && date -d "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1) of @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873507/vic-seedoubleyew is best one at least for linux, but it gives error as we can not directly compare/match regex in if statement. We should put the regex in a variable and then we should compare/match that variable in if statement. Moreover second part of if condition does not return a boolean value so this part will also cause error.

So I have done slight modification in the above formula and this modification can also be customized further for various other formats or combination of them.

```
DATEVALUE=2019-11-12
REGEX='^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
if [[ $DATEVALUE =~ $REGEX ]] ; then
    date -d $DATEVALUE 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "RIGHT DATE"
   else 
    echo "WRONG DATE"
  fi
else
 echo "WRONG FORMAT"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another regex to validate the date:

```
"$1" =~ [0-9]{4}/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]$|3[0-1]$)
```

This regex has some shortcomings, it doesn't check if the day of month is valid for the specified month.

Answer (score -2):

Blockquote

```
DATE = "$*"

[[ "${DATE}" != @(((([123][0]|[012][1-9])|3[1])?([ \/._-])(0[13578]|1[02])?([ \/._-])(19|20)[0-9][0-9])|(([123][0]|[012][1-9])?([ \/._-])\
(0[469]|11)?([ \/._-])(19|20)[0-9][0-9])|(([12][0]|[01][1-9]|2[1-8])?([ \/._-])02?([ \/._-])(19|20)[0-9][0-9])|(29?([ \/._-])02?([ \/._-])\
(19|20(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])))) ]] && echo error || echo good)
```