# validate date in unix for DD-MM-YYYY format

Tags: bash, unix, arguments

How to validate the date in `Unix`.
Where the date format is `DD-MM-YYYY`.
For example if i run one script `./ValidateDate.sh DD-MM-YYYY` then it should check that the date is in this format and also that the date exists.
If date is valid and in above format then proceed for next else print message 'Invalid date'

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validade Date Format in a Shell Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731346/validade-date-format-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: The answer there doesn't work for dmy.

Comment: If you have any influence over the requirements, I encourage you to use the international standard format `YYYY-MM-DD` rather than the ambiguous `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Answer (score 3):

Well... This is a fine can o' worms.

Any shell script that you create may not work on all of the various flavors of Unix/Linux.

The BSD date command (found on OS X and Solaris) does a great job at taking in the date and verifying the format. It requires you to specify your date format, but once you do, it has no problems:

```
if date -j -f "%d-%m-%Y" "$DATE" 2>&1 > /dev/null # No output
then
    echo "ERROR: Date '$DATE' is not a valid format."
    exit 2
else
    echo "Date is '$DATE'."
fi
```

Linux and other systems that use GNU's date can also validate the date, but use a different syntax:

```
date -d "$DATE" 2>&1 /dev/null   # With a bit of luck this will work...
if $? -ne 0
then
    echo "ERROR: Date '$DATE' is not a valid format."
else
    echo "Date is '$DATE'."
fi
```

I say *With a bit of luck* because it's up to the `date` command to figure out your date's format. This normally works, and will work with your `YYYY-MM-DD` format, but it can be confusing:

Imagine this:

```
$ DATE="15/6/2014"              # It's June 15, 2014
$ date -d "$DATE"
date: invalid date `15/6/2014'  # Invalid?
```

That's because in my timezone, the `dd/mm/yyyy` format isn't a valid format. In my timezone, the date should be `mm/dd/yyyy`. To get around this you can use [Wintermute's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27380543/368630) suggestion and format the date into ISO format before using GNU's date format.

A more *universal* possibility is to use Perl or Python to figure out if the date is correct:

```
if perl -mTime::Piece -e "Time::Piece->strptime(\"$DATE\", \"%Y-%m-%d\")" 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "ERROR: Date '$DATE' is not a valid format."
else
    echo "Date is '$DATE'."
fi
```

This Perl oneliner will return a non-zero error status if `$DATE` isn't a valid date in `%Y-%m-%d` format.

Comment: My awk one should also work on all flavours(as long as they have awk obviously).

Comment: `gawk` (which is aliased to `gawk` on Linux) has the `strptime` function, but not standard `awk` found on BSD systems. Your script won't work on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

awk way

```
awk 'split($0,a,"-"){print strftime("%d-%m-%Y",mktime(a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" 00 00 00"))==$0?"valid":"not valid"}' <<< "31-12-1992"
```

It Converts the string to epoch,converts epoch back then checks against the original.

Edit:

Thought i would add after testing this works for dates
FROM `01-01-0`
TO `31-12-2147483647`

Although a drawback is after you go below the year 1000 you have to remove leading zeros from the year.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the date with the `date` utility, but you first have to transform the input into something it can understand. I suggest ISO representation (always). It could, for example, look like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 PATTERN='\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\+\)'

 # if the pattern doesn't match, this will give date an empty string, so it will fail as expected.
 if date -d $(echo "$1" | sed -n "/$PATTERN/ { s/$PATTERN/\3-\2-\1/; p }") > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
     echo valid
 else
     echo invalid
 fi
```

Comment: Any reason for doing `sed -n ... p` instead of just default sed ?

Comment: The `p` is conditional. It's only executed if the line matches the pattern. Otherwise, input that doesn't match the pattern but is recognized by date would be considered valid.

Comment: Note that `date -d` is a GNU-specific extension and not part of POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily if you are willing to break the validation into two steps. First, check that the string is in the right format:

```
date=$1
[[ $date =~ ([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9]+) ]] || { printf "Invalid date format\n"; exit 1; }
```

If that test passes, you can extract the day, month, and year fields, then verify that each falls in the correct range.

```
day=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
year=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

thirty_one_days='0[1-9]|[12][0--9]|3[01]'
thirty_days='0[1-9]|[12][0--9]|30'
twenty_eight_days='0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]'
case $month in
    01|03|05|07|08|10|12)
        [[ $day =~ $thirty_one_days ]] ;;
    04|06|09|11)
        [[ $day =~ $thirty_days ]] ;;
    02)
        # 1-28, but 29 OK in a leap year.
        [[ $day =~ $twenty_eight_days ]] ||
            (( year % 4 == 0 && $year % 400 == 0 && day == 29 ))
    *)
         false
 esac || { print "Invalid date\n"; exit 1; }
```