# Valid shell script input date format

Tags: linux, shell

I  have used the method posted for the following question, but I still have some issues.

[Validate date format in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731346/validate-date-format-in-a-shell-script)

```
$ ./check_date.sh 20190109
Input date format 20190109        # this should report error!

$ ./check_date.sh 2019-0109
[ERROR]: Invalid input date format 2019-0109

$ ./check_date.sh 2019-01-09
Input date format 2019-01-09

$ cat ./check_date.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "[ERROR]: Invalid input date format $1"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Input date format $1"
fi
```

As you can see, I expect the input `20190109` will cause the script to report ERROR but instead it works without errors.

In summary, I need to validate the input date string so that it strictly follows the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Question> What should I do to get the script work as expected?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to validate the format, or do you want to validate the format and the date?

Comment: It is best if I can validate both. Thank you!

Comment: You should send error messages to stderr: `echo "[ERROR]: Invalid input date format $1" >&2`

Comment: The format option for the date command will not check / enforce the input date string in any way, it's used solely for formatting the output. A format like `20190109` is accepted by the date command as input to the the `-d, --date=STRING` switch so you won't be able to use this approach to validate your format requirement.

Comment: Also, just as a side note: the format does not need to be quoted if it has no spaces (since it's literal and won't change), however, it's better to quote the argument should a date string with spaces be passed in `date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following test should work:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ [0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ]] && date -d "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   success
else
   error
fi
```

It first checks if the format is correct NNNN-NN-NN, and then used `date` to check if the date is valid.

**Why is your original code not working:** You wrote:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You "assumed" that the string `'+%Y-%m-%d'` defined the input format, but it actually defines the output format. Date is capable to take a various collection of input strings and convert them accordingly:

```
$ date -d "yesterday" '+%F'
$ date -d "2019-01-01 + 10 days" '+%F'
$ date -d "5 fortnight ago" '+%F'
$ date -d "12/13/1099" '+%F'
```

You cannot force date to assume the input date string to have a given format.